# MySQL: JOIN and Conditional Statement

Tags: mysql, join

Can comeone help me to decipher the right logic of code needed for my query? I just can't find solutions about this or maybe my search queries are just vague. Lol.

I made a query and thought before it was fine but I just realized, just now, the inaccuracy of these. Here are what I've tried:

From a search page, for example we have this variable:

```
$variable = !empty($_POST["variable"]) ? $_POST['variable'] : "";
```

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
WHERE table2.column LIKE '%$variable%'
```

**RESULT 1**

- If `$variable` has no value, only rows with respective data from `table2` are displaying.
- If `$variable` has a value, rows with respective data from `table2` and matching value are displaying.

---

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
     AND table2.column LIKE '%$variable%'
```

**RESULT 2**

- If `$variable` has no value, all rows are displaying.
- If `$variable` has a value, all rows are still displaying.

---

**DESIRED RESULT**

- If `$variable` has no value, all rows will be displayed.
- If `$variable` has a value, rows with respective data from `table2`
  and matching value will be displayed.

I already tried using `IF`, `CASE` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but still no luck. Am I forgetting something with here? Or I'm doing it wrong (which is the truth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've just gave another shot with `IF` clause and figured out the simplest query that I can think of. **It's now giving the desired result**, here's my query:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
WHERE IF('$variable' != '', table2.column = '$variable', 1 = 1)
```

Successfully, I placed that `IF()` clause in the right place. If you guys have thoughts about this code or have a very better one than this, kindly share it :)

---

> **[ADDITIONAL]**
>
> This is an [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140809/mysql-join-and-conditional-statement/140818?noredirect=1#comment266637_140818) from @ypercubeᵀᴹ and I love it!
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     ...
>     ...
> FROM table1
> LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id 
> WHERE table2.column = '$variable' OR '$variable' = ''
> ```

Comment: try `FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id WHERE (table2.column = '$variable' OR '$variable' = '')`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Awesome sauce! That's simpler from what I currently had! I added it to the answer. Thanks :D